# Finding Tagged Items - cakephp Tags Plugin

Tags: php, cakephp, tags, cakedc

I am trying to get the Tags Plugin (https://github.com/CakeDC/tags) to work using the find by method (pagination) as outlined at the following example:

https://github.com/CakeDC/tags/wiki/Find-tagged-objects

The tags seem to be setup and working as I can add tags to my 'items' model but I cannot search by.

I have my code as follows (function index):

```
if (isset($this->passedArgs['by'])) {
            $this->paginate['Tagged'] = array(
                    'model' => 'Item',
                    'tagged',
                    'by' => $this->passedArgs['by']);
            $items = $this->paginate('Tagged');
    } else {
            $this->Item->recursive = 1;
            $items = $this->paginate();
    }
    $this->set('items', $items);
    $this->set('tags', $this->Item->Tagged->find('cloud', array('limit' => 10)));
```

When I click though from my tags cloud I get this error:

Indirect modification of overloaded property ItemsController::$paginate has no effect [APP/Controller/ItemsController.php, line 20]

Line 20 is: `$this->paginate['Tagged'] = array(`

Any idea where I am going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue was I needed to setup paginate in the controller first.

```
public $paginate = array();
```